# Unity AR works on one device and not the other, despite the fact that they are the same model and API level

Tags: unity, augmented-reality

I hope someone can help me with this weird issue.

We have an app with AR functionality, we have been building and running on device to test and have had no issues. We then did a full build and manually installed it, also works fine with no issues, when we go into the AR scene it asks for permission of the camera and everything works as expected. We sent the build to the client with the same device and they got a black screen the first time, then we clicked on another scene and the app crashed, without the app asking for camera permission.

When we manually set it in app settings it also does not work.

Unity version is 2020.3.44f1
previous solutions as seen on this forum do not work for me.

Publishing settings are set to IL2CPP with ARM64

ARCore is ticked in project settings.

AR Foundation and AR Core are 4.1.13

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which previous solutions did you try? Link to them please, so we don't accidentally repeat advice you've already tested and found inapplicable.

Comment: First, you can ask the client to check the memory available (SSD or hard drive) on their device. If they don't have lots of memory available, strange behaviors can occur. Second, ask to see if the RAM available on the client's phone is large enough. If necessary, ask clients to close all other apps and only run your app to see if that works better. Lack of available RAM can cause the app to crash.